# angularjs: how to go back to previous page from a nested view when clicking back button of browser?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I have two pages, **index.html** and **tabs.html**. **tabs.html** is a nested structure, it has a tabs component and every tab is bind to a state(**tab1**, **tab2**, **tab3**). When changing from **index.html** to **tabs.html**, the state change path will be: **index** -> **tabs** -> **tab1**. When you click other tabs, the state change path maybe: **index** -> **tabs** -> **tab1** -> **tab2**. Now if you click the back button of the browser, you will just go back from **tab2** to **tab1**, that means you are still in **tabs.html**. Now my question is, is there any good method to realize when clicking the back button of browser, I can go back to **index.html** not just the previous state?

Comment: Personally, I don't like sites where you directly fall back too much by clicking the back button... I like to be where I've been before the last click.

Comment: Instead of that, why you don't use back button which always go to redirected states

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Because back operation in browser works with URLs, you can remove url property in state definition for tab1, tab2 and tab3 states, and you have to link them just with `ui-sref`.

Now if you back in browser you will go to `index.html`

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply, that solves my problem!!